# main domain and subdomain hosted on different servers?

Tags: subdomain, firebase-hosting

This is just a feasibility question. I currently have a domain `mydomain.com` hosted by `webflow`. The main domain will be used as a landing page. I also have a subdomain named `sub.mydomain.com` which I want to write some `reactjs` code and host it in firebase hosting. Is it doable? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's doable. I just need to add an A record for sub.mydomain.com and point to the IP of firebase hosting.

Comment: How did you find the firebase IP address? I need the hosting for heroku.